# How to get name of database C# Winforms LocalDb v11.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I trying to restore database programatically; for that I need to know the name of the database.

What I have done so far is this:

```
string con = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(con);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");

conn.Open();
string server = builder.DataSource;
string database = builder["Database"] as string;

MessageBox.Show(database.ToString());
```

but when I try to access database string in the message box, I get an empty result. Please help me to find what my problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database is not specified, you have to add:

```
Database=myDataBase
```

to your connection string:

```
string con = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Database=myDataBase";
```

Comment: it worked but there is exception this database cannot use the database other database is used can you help mee

Comment: Try to solve this problem, look for existing information on the internet, if there is no solution just post a new question.